# How to style the Facebook comments plugin, like 'real' Facebook comments?

Tags: css, facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-comments

I'm trying to write a Facebook app that supports comments that look like native facebook comments.

The comments plugin does not use the same styling that is used throughout the Facebook site.

Setting a custom comments stylesheet has been deprecated (June, 2012) in favour of their new plugin system that puts everything in an iframe.

What should I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First: If you want to copy something without the usage of a social plugin, be careful with the design guidelines of facebook:

> https://www.facebook.com/brandpermissions/index.php

That being said, you already answered your question. Custom stylesheets are deprecated, so you can only change the colorscheme (dark/light) of the comments plugin. The only way to make it look like facebook is to program it on your own. Which will never be the same, unfortunately, because the social plugin doesn´t even need the user to authorize any app for commenting...